# Error NullPointerException en JAVA, no puedo resolverlo

Tags: java

No he podido encontrar donde está la falla en el código que a continuación copio. Se trata de gestionar aeropuertos, la aplicación consiste en 6 clases, la clase Aeropuerto de la que heredan otras dos AeropuertoPrivado y AeropuertoPublico y de la que depende la clase Compania, la clase Compania de la que depende la clase Vuelo y la clase Vuelo de la que depende Pasajero. La falla me lo da al ejecutar el Principal indicandome que está en la clase Compania en el método getVuelo que recibe por parámetro un String. Copio la misma:

```
public class Compania {
private String nombre;
private Vuelo listaVuelos[]=new Vuelo[10];
private int numVuelo=0;

public Compania(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public Compania(String nombre, Vuelo v[] ){
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.listaVuelos=v;
    this.numVuelo=v.length;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

//insertar un vuelo
public void insertarVuelo(Vuelo nuevoVuelo){
    listaVuelos[numVuelo]=nuevoVuelo;
    numVuelo++;
}
//Retornar vuelo según la ubicación en el listado
public Vuelo getVuelo(int i){
    return listaVuelos[i];
}
//Retornar vuelo según el identificador del mismo
public Vuelo getVuelo(String ident){
    boolean encontrado=false;
    int i=0;
    Vuelo vueloEncontrado=null;
    while ((!encontrado)&&(i<listaVuelos.length)){
        if (ident.equals(listaVuelos[i].getIdentificador())){
            encontrado=true;
            vueloEncontrado=listaVuelos[i];
        }
        i++;
    } 
  return vueloEncontrado;  
}
}
```

y en las líneas 15 y 60 de la clase Principal:

```
public class Principal {
static final int num=4;
static Aeropuerto [] aeropuerto=new Aeropuerto[num];
static Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);


public static void main(String[] args) {
     
    insertarDatosAeropuerto(aeropuerto);//Linea 15
    menu();
}
public static void insertarDatosAeropuerto(Aeropuerto a[]){
    aeropuerto[0]= new AeropuertoPublico(5600000, "Ezeiza", "Buenos Aires", "Argentina");
    aeropuerto[0].insertarCompania(new Compania("Aerolineas Argentinas"));
    aeropuerto[0].insertarCompania(new Compania("LATAM"));
    aeropuerto[0].getCompania("Aerolineas Argentinas").insertarVuelo(new Vuelo("V01", "Buenos Aires", "Mendoza", 25000, 150));
    aeropuerto[0].getCompania("Aerolineas Argentinas").insertarVuelo(new Vuelo("V02", "Buenos Aires", "Salta", 23000,150));
    aeropuerto[0].getCompania("LATAM").insertarVuelo(new Vuelo("V12","Buenos Aires","Paris",2500000,200));
    aeropuerto[0].getCompania("Aerolineas Argentinas").getVuelo("V01").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Carla Mighella", "123ARG", "Argentina"));
    aeropuerto[0].getCompania("Aerolineas Argentinas").getVuelo("V01").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Ezequiel Caglioni", "456ARG", "Argentina"));
    aeropuerto[0].getCompania("Aerolineas Argentinas").getVuelo("V02").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Fabian Garcia", "752ARG", "Argentina"));
    aeropuerto[0].getCompania("LATAM").getVuelo("V12").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Juan Gomez", "852ARG", "Argentina"));
    
    aeropuerto[1]= new AeropuertoPublico(5600000, "Jorge Newbery", "Buenos Aires", "Argentina");
    aeropuerto[1].insertarCompania(new Compania("Aerolineas Argentinas"));
    aeropuerto[1].insertarCompania(new Compania("LATAM"));
    aeropuerto[1].getCompania("Aerolineas Argentinas").insertarVuelo(new Vuelo("V15", "Buenos Aires", "San Juan", 21000, 150));
    aeropuerto[1].getCompania("Aerolineas Argentinas").insertarVuelo(new Vuelo("V98", "Buenos Aires", "Jujuy", 27000,150));
    aeropuerto[1].getCompania("LATAM").insertarVuelo(new Vuelo("V63","Buenos Aires","Montevideo",25800,150));
    aeropuerto[1].getCompania("Aerolineas Argentinas").getVuelo("V15").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Gustavo Holguin", "7541JU", "Peruano"));
    aeropuerto[1].getCompania("Aerolineas Argentinas").getVuelo("V15").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Sara Guzman", "2563LJ", "Argentina"));
    aeropuerto[1].getCompania("Aerolineas Argentinas").getVuelo("V98").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Vanina Ledesma", "562KJ", "Argentina"));
    aeropuerto[1].getCompania("LATAM").getVuelo("V63").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Luis Fernendez", "5614KJ", "Argentina"));
    
    aeropuerto[2]= new AeropuertoPublico(5600000, "Aeropuerto de Cordoba", "Cordoba", "Argentina");
    aeropuerto[2].insertarCompania(new Compania("Aerolineas Argentinas"));
    aeropuerto[2].insertarCompania(new Compania("LATAM"));
    aeropuerto[2].getCompania("Aerolineas Argentinas").insertarVuelo(new Vuelo("V45", "Cordoba", "San Luis", 15000, 150));
    aeropuerto[2].getCompania("Aerolineas Argentinas").insertarVuelo(new Vuelo("V24", "Cordoba", "Jujuy", 27000,150));
    aeropuerto[2].getCompania("LATAM").insertarVuelo(new Vuelo("V74","Cordoba","Asunción",27800,150));
    aeropuerto[2].getCompania("Aerolineas Argentinas").getVuelo("V45").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Federico Hernendez", "1425HG", "Argentino"));
    aeropuerto[2].getCompania("Aerolineas Argentinas").getVuelo("V45").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Delia venegas", "5623FD", "Argentina"));
    aeropuerto[2].getCompania("Aerolineas Argentinas").getVuelo("V24").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Luisa Fernendez", "5478LK", "Argentina"));
    aeropuerto[2].getCompania("LATAM").getVuelo("V74").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Miguel Del Carril", "7854GF", "Argentina"));
    
    aeropuerto[3]= new AeropuertoPrivado("Volando vamos", "Tigre", "Argentina");
    aeropuerto[3].insertarCompania(new Compania("Del Sur"));
    aeropuerto[3].insertarCompania(new Compania("La linda"));
    aeropuerto[3].getCompania("Del Sur").insertarVuelo(new Vuelo("452", "Tigre", "Quilmes", 15620, 50));
    aeropuerto[3].getCompania("Del Sur").insertarVuelo(new Vuelo("562", "Tigre", "Luján", 18000,50));
    aeropuerto[3].getCompania("La linda").insertarVuelo(new Vuelo("254","Tigre","Ezeiza",15800,50));
    aeropuerto[3].getCompania("Del Sur").getVuelo("452").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Juana Sarmiento", "54278", "Argentino"));
    aeropuerto[3].getCompania("Del Sur").getVuelo("452").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Ester Gauna", "5236", "Argentina"));
    aeropuerto[3].getCompania("Del Sur").getVuelo("254").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Omar calvente", "4710", "Argentina"));//Línea 60
    aeropuerto[3].getCompania("La linda").getVuelo("562").insertarPasajeros(new Pasajero("Ana Sastre", "6302", "Argentina"));
}
public static void menu(){
    int opcion;
    do{
        System.out.println("\tMENU:");
        System.out.println("1. Ver aeropuertos gestionados (Públicos o privados)");  
        System.out.println("2. Ver empresas (Aeropuertos privados) o subvenciones (Aeropuertos públicos)");
        System.out.println("3. Listar compañias de un aeropuerto");
        System.out.println("4. Listar vuelos por compañias");
        System.out.println("5. Listar posibles vuelos de origen a destino");
        System.out.println("6. Salir");
        System.out.println("Opción");
        opcion= entrada.nextInt();
        switch (opcion){
            case 1:
                //Ver aeropuertos gestionados (Públicos o privados)
                mostrarDatosAeropuertos(aeropuerto);
                break;
            case 2: 
                //Ver empresas (Aeropuertos privados) o subvenciones (Aeropuertos públicos)
                break;
            case 3:
                //Listar compañias de un aeropuerto
                break;
            case 4: 
                //Listar vuelos por compañias
                break;
            case 5:
                //Listar posibles vuelos de origen a destino
                break;
            case 6: break;
            default: System.out.println("Se equivocó, no existe la opción ingresada");
        }
    } while (opcion !=6);
    
        
}
public static void mostrarDatosAeropuertos(Aeropuerto a[]){
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        if (a[i] instanceof AeropuertoPrivado){
            System.out.println("Aeropuerto Privado");
            System.out.println("Nombre: "+a[i].getNombre());
            System.out.println("Ciudad: "+a[i].getCiudad());
            System.out.println("Pais: "+a[i].getPais());
        } else{
            System.out.println("Aeropuerto Público");
            System.out.println("Nombre: "+a[i].getNombre());
            System.out.println("Ciudad: "+a[i].getCiudad());
            System.out.println("Pais: "+a[i].getPais());
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
}
```

Clase Aeropuerto:

```
public class Aeropuerto {
private String nombre;
private String ciudad;
private String pais;
private Compania listaCompanias[]=new Compania[10];
private int numCompania;

public Aeropuerto(String nombre, String ciudad, String pais) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
    this.pais = pais;
    this.numCompania=0;
}
public Aeropuerto(String nombre, String ciudad, String pais, Compania c[]) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
    this.pais = pais;
    this.listaCompanias=c;
    this.numCompania=c.length;
    
}
public void insertarCompania(Compania nuevaCompania){
    listaCompanias[numCompania]=nuevaCompania;
    numCompania++;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public String getCiudad() {
    return ciudad;
}

public String getPais() {
    return pais;
}

public Compania[] getListaCompanias() {
    return listaCompanias;
}

public int getNumCompania() {
    return numCompania;
}
//Buscar una compañia según numero en el listado
public Compania getCompania(int i){
    return listaCompanias[i];
}
//Buscar una compañia por su nombre
public Compania getCompania(String nombre){
    boolean encontrado=false;
    int i=0;
    Compania c=null;
    while ((!encontrado)&&(i<listaCompanias.length)){
        if (nombre.equals(listaCompanias[i].getNombre())){
            c=listaCompanias[i];
            encontrado=true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

}
Clase Vuelo:

```
public class Vuelo {
    private String identificador, ciudadOrigen, ciudadDestino;
    private double precio;
    private int numMaxPasajeros;
    private int numActualPasajeros;
    private Pasajero listaPasajeros[];

    public Vuelo(String identificador, String ciudadOrigen, String ciudadDestino, double precio, int numMaxPasajeros) {
        this.identificador = identificador;
        this.ciudadOrigen = ciudadOrigen;
        this.ciudadDestino = ciudadDestino;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.numMaxPasajeros = numMaxPasajeros;
        this.numActualPasajeros=0;
        this.listaPasajeros= new Pasajero [numMaxPasajeros];
    }
   public void insertarPasajeros(Pasajero nuevoPasajero){
       listaPasajeros[numActualPasajeros]=nuevoPasajero;
       numActualPasajeros++;
   }

    public String getIdentificador() {
        return identificador;
    }

    public String getCiudadOrigen() {
        return ciudadOrigen;
    }

    public String getCiudadDestino() {
        return ciudadDestino;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public int getNumMaxPasajeros() {
        return numMaxPasajeros;
    }

    public int getNumActualPasajeros() {
        return numActualPasajeros;
    }
    //Encontrar pasajero según ubicación en la lista
   public Pasajero getPasajero(int i){
       return listaPasajeros[i];
   }
   //Encontrar pasajero sgún número de pasaporte
   public Pasajero getPasajero(String pasap){
       boolean encontrado=false;
       int i=0;
       Pasajero pas=null;
       while ((!encontrado)&&(i<listaPasajeros.length)){
           if (pasap.equals(listaPasajeros[i].getPasaporte())){
               encontrado=true;
               pas=listaPasajeros[i];
            }
           i++;
       }
       return pas;
   }
    
    
}
```

Clase AeropuertoPrivado:

```
 public class AeropuertoPrivado extends Aeropuerto {
    private String listaEmpresas[]=new String [10];
    private int numEmpresa;

    public AeropuertoPrivado(String nombre, String ciudad, String pais) {
        super(nombre, ciudad, pais);
    }

    public AeropuertoPrivado(String nombre, String ciudad, String pais, Compania[] c, String e[]) {
        super(nombre, ciudad, pais, c);
        this.listaEmpresas=e;
        this.numEmpresa=e.length;//Máximo de empresas que va a tener
    }
   //Método para insertar todas las empresas de una
    public void insertarEmpresas(String e[]){
        this.listaEmpresas=e;
        this.numEmpresa=e.length;
    }
    //Método para insertar una empresa
    public void insertarEmpresa(String e){
        this.listaEmpresas[numEmpresa]=e;
        this.numEmpresa++;
    }

    public String[] getListaEmpresas() {
        return listaEmpresas;
    }

    public int getNumEmpresa() {
        return numEmpresa;
    }
    
    
}
```

Clase AeropuertpPublico:

```
public class AeropuertoPublico extends Aeropuerto {
private double subvención;

public AeropuertoPublico(String nombre, String ciudad, String pais) {
    super(nombre, ciudad, pais);
}

public AeropuertoPublico(String nombre, String ciudad, String pais, Compania[] c) {
    super(nombre, ciudad, pais, c);
    
}

public AeropuertoPublico(double subvención, String nombre, String ciudad, String pais) {
    super(nombre, ciudad, pais);
    this.subvención = subvención;
}

public double getSubvención() {
    return subvención;
}
```

}

Sé que el error me está diciendo que se está apuntando a un Null pero no sé como subsanar el error. Agradezco que me puedan ayudar! Saludos!!

Comment: En casi todos los IDE puedes marcar puntos de interrupción, el código se detendrá en ellos. Puedes poner un punto de interrupción antes del objeto nulo e inspeccionar cada objeto hasta ese punto para saber qué es lo que está causando el NPE. Es cuestión de aprender a depurar el código.

Comment: faltan las clases Aeropuerto y Vuelo, es mas facil ayudarte si nuestros IDE's pueden ver todo el codigo

Comment: Hola!! Gracias A. Cedano, no lo hice ni sé bien como se hace para me pongo en campaña y ElFuturo Llego no subí todo porque el sistema no me dejaba publicar la pregunta, ahora voy a intentarlo nuevamente. Gracias!

Comment: los pequeños detalles siempre nos jugaran en contra fíjate tu código metodo insertarDatosAeropuerto(), en la posición[3] del array la linda asignas vuelo 254  delSur asignas vuelo 562 sin embargo vos esperas obtener el vuelo delSur con 254 y el de la linda 562  ,intercambia esos valores y veras la magia ;) saludos

Comment: Nah no sabes las veces que lo volví a revisar y no lo ví!!! Gracias, gracias, gracias!!